# Converting JasperPrint to a File

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Im with a different problem... I've googled a little but havent found anything about my problem so im asking here...
I have an object JasperPrint where i generate the document...
The problem is that i need to create a java.io.File from this JasperPrint without saving the file on the computer.

What do i need to do is: send a file by email. And this file must be generated by the jasperreport. I can't save the stream on the machine to delete it later... so i need to take the file in memory or something like that in runtime...

So... i have my object jasperprint and need to get a java.io.File from this one...
Someone knows what do can i do?

Andrew... couldnt answer it at comment so im writing it here...
In javax.mail i've done like this:

```
File fileAttachment = myfile;
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileAttachment);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileAttachment.getName());
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

and its working when i pass him a file from my machine...
So i think its gonna work when i use a java.io.File even if its only on memory...

Comment: According to your updated question I updated my answer ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate the report as PDF(or other format) and send it as a file with Jasper.
JRXlsExporter

some snippet:

```
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap(), jasperReports); 
long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:/output/JasperReport.pdf")); 
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, output); 

// coding For Excel: 


JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter(); 
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JA SPER_PRINT, print); 
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OU TPUT_STREAM, output); 
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS _ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.TRUE); 
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS _AUTO_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE); 
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS _WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE); 
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS _REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE); 
exporterXLS.exportReport();
```

Comment: Does JRXlsExporter have any method that actually sends an email? (BTW, he only wants XlsExporter if he wants to send an XLS file. There are exporters for each type.)

Comment: Don;t know if sends mail but once you have file you can sent it !

Comment: When you pass that outputstream and say exporterXLS to "exportReport" then this outputstream recieve the data from the report right? Im trying to convert my outputstream into inputstream.. Now i just need to know how to convert inputstream to file without creating a file on disc..

Comment: @Cris, I think the OP was trying to *avoid* creating a file to send.

Comment: problem solved... i've used the JRPdfExporter with outputstream... Then converted the output to input and then i've created a tempfile to him... :) Thanks everybody =D

Answer (score 2):

You can write it to a `OutputStream` and then use this stream to create the e-mail attachement. Here is an example for a XLS exporter.

```
JasperPrint jsPrint;
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jsPrint);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);
exporterXLS.exportReport();
```

If you want to send this, you can create a `ByteArrayDataSource` (see your updated question) instead of a `FileDataSource`:

```
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
ByteArrayDataSource bads = new ByteArrayDataSource(in,mimeType);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to send it as a .print file or something universally readable like .pdf?

I don't think it matters, though. The issue here isn't with JasperPrint, it's with the java**x** mail [classes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html), which have a steep learning curve. Look particularly at `javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart` .

Comment: @Igor, Thor is showing the way with the ByteArray stuff, which by the way can (if I recall correctly) take piped stuff from the pdf converter.

Comment: yeah i saw it rigth now... but im gonna need the file for another operations on the system... I think the way he did it its work too..